# GWT. How does internationalization work in UiBinder?

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, uibinder, gwt2

I'm trying to write my first project with using of GWT.
And I do not understand the principles of the internationalization of GWT application with UiBinder.
I used JSP before now. I clearly understand the internationalization of the technology:

```
<fmt:message key="myValue" />
```

In GWT the similar tag can have some content:

```
<ui:msg key="myKey" description="myDescription">My content</ui:msg>
```

It is unclear for me. What does the content of this tag mean? What is sense in it? All the data as I understand it should be taken from `.properties` files.
And what do the attributes `key` and `description` means? What values they should contain?

I would be very grateful if someone can available explain how does internationalization work in UiBinder. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

[UiBinder i18n](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinderI18n) works by generating a [`Messages` interface](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Messages.html) under-the-hood, so to understand UiBinder i18n, you actually only need to understand GWT i18n.

Each `ui:msg` is turned into a method in the interface, each attribute of `ui:msg` is turned into an annotation on that method, and the content of the `ui:msg` is turned into the value of a `@DefaultMessage` annotation on the method, with each widget or `ui:ph` turned into a placeholder and resolved *at runtime*.
Similarly, some attributes attributes on the top-level `ui:UiBinder` element are turned into annotations on the generated `Messages` interface.

In GWT i18n, you can have one locale integrated into your code, in the form of annotations (`@DefaultMessage` within a `Messages` interface), without the need for a `*.properties` file for that locale. The locale is given in a `@DefaultLocale` annotation on the interface (`ui:defaultLocale` in UiBinder). Only messages for other locales have to be provided in `*.properties` files.
(note that you cannot use all features of `Messages` from UiBinder: plurals, selection, optional arguments, etc.)

So, to answer your more specific questions: [`key`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocalizableResource.Key.html) gives the key used to lookup the message in the `*.properties` file (for all locales besides the `ui:defaultLocale`, where the message is given right in the UiBinder file), and [`description`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocalizableResource.Description.html), as well as [`meaning`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocalizableResource.Meaning.html), are only a hint for translators.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do uibinder internationalization is follow the steps of this blog: http://joergviola.blogspot.com.es/2011/07/gwt-uibuilder-internationalisation.html.

I have tested it and it works like a charm!